# Coreplot - selecting area below line

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using coreplot to draw a scatter plot like that:
[image]

I use 4 different plots (as coloured) and create a "bar like" feeling by adding 0-value points at the beginning/end of each "bar".
I want to determine which bar was selected by the user and then change alphas of other plots.

I've tried using

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    //here I translate the selected point to Data points coordinates 
    //and check which of the plot sources has value >0 (that means bar is visible)
    //and is closest to the selected point
}
```

This method works, but when I want to scroll the data, the method above is called as well.

There must be some easier solution to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a scatter plot to draw a bar plot? Bar plots have delegate methods to tell you when the bar is selected directly.

Comment: It's not really a bar plot. Those are constant values (1/2/3/4) that indicate different phases I want to display. Their width is changing as the phases where happening in different times. I thought it will be proper to be drawn using scatter plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `YES` from your delegate method to inform the plot space that you've taken action on the event and it does not need to start the scroll. You may need to handle the other events, too, so your app can differentiate between a tap and a drag.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be easier to be done, but looks like I am not going to miss custom gesture handling.